# Is there a Application. that closes both a picture and text in C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am writing a program in Unity for my main menu. I got the Quit button, it just takes

```
public void ExitGame()
    {

        Application.Quit();

    }
```

But I need something that only exits the window not the game. Is it Application.Quit and I'm just paranoid? Or is something that I don't know of. Please help!

Edit: Would

```
 public void ExitOptions()
    {
        optionMenu.enabled = false
    }
```

work?
Edit 2: I'm suposed to add code here: I will make a short cleaner version after I'm done writing it

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class menuScript : MonoBehaviour {

    public Canvas quitMenu;
    public Button startText;
    public Button exitText;
    public Canvas optionMenu;
    public Button WASDText;
    public Button arrowText;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()

    {
        quitMenu = quitMenu.GetComponent<Canvas>();
        startText = startText.GetComponent<Button>();
        exitText = exitText.GetComponent<Button>();
        quitMenu.enabled = false;
        optionMenu = optionMenu.GetComponent<Canvas>();
        WASDText = WASDText.GetComponent<Button>();
        arrowText = arrowText.GetComponent<Button>();


    }


    public void ExitPress()
    {
        quitMenu.enabled = true;
        startText.enabled = false;
        exitText.enabled = false;
    }

    public void OptionPress()
    {
        optionMenu.enabled = true;
        WASDText.enabled = true;
        arrowText.enabled = false;
    }

    public void NoPress()
    {
        optionMenu.enabled = false;
        startText.enabled = true;
        exitText.enabled = true;

    }

    public void WASDPress()
    {
        optionMenu.enabled = true;
        WASDText.enabled = true;
        arrowText.enabled = false;
    }

    public void ArroPress()
    {
        optionMenu.enabled = true
        WASDText.enabled = false
        arrowText.enabled = true
    }
    public void StartLevel()
    {
        Application.LoadLevel (1);

    }

    public void ExitGame()
    {
        Application.Quit();

    }

    public void ExitOptions()
    {
        optionMenu.enabled = false
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably need to use `this.Close()`, but its not clear what you mean by exiting the window and not the game. Do you mean you are using a GUI component and you want to close it? Can you show more of the code for the class that the `ExitGame` method is defined in?

Comment: I am using a UI image with text as children. I don't understand what you meant but here is the script, I plan on separating it into two different scripts once I'm done

Comment: Ill make a cleaner short version when I finish

Comment: Please add all this source code in the question. Comments are meant for addressing doubts. You're making a mess of the question.

Comment: okay. I will do that.

Answer (score 3):

If `Text` component is nested in `Image` component, justs call:

```
optionMenu.SetActive(false);
```

It will make it inactive along with all of its children.

If you are closing it from another Unity3D UI element, you can attach `EventTrigger` or if it is a `Button`, you can drag and drop `Image` to it's `OnClick()` event and leave checkbox unchecked (in example below it will enable object of name "Canvas2" beacause checkbox is checked):

[image]